# How does t-SNE preserves embedding orders?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, embeddings, dimensionality

According to [the triplet loss Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplet_loss):

> t-SNE (t-distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding) preserves embedding orders via probability distributions, whereas triplet loss works directly on embedded distances.

I don't understand how does t-SNE preserves embedding order from the description given by its Wikipedia page.

I am trying to understand this claim in order to translate the page into other languages. I don't have a very quick understanding of maths, don't be afraid to explain it as if I was a teenager.

Answer (score 0):

You just to look at the [method of T-SNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding). It "computes probabilities $p_{ij}$ that are proportional to the similarity of objects ${x} _{i}$ and ${x} _{j}$". This means the same as the sentence that you have already quoted:

> t-SNE (t-distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding) **preserves embedding orders via probability distributions**, whereas triplet loss works directly on embedded distances.